# Regular expression to delete a word starting with sample_[some number] and ending with comma

Tags: regex, notepad++

I need a regular expression to delete a word which start with a fixed word concatenated with a some random number and ends a comma.

For example;

```
there is some sample_3131 , which needs to full out
sample_3300 , a body having great sample_91001 , power.
```

any ideas on how to do it using notepad++ ?

Comment: Yes, use regex. What have you tried, where is the problem? It seems to be trivial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is the Regex for "sample_3131,", I suppose there is no space between 3131 and comma:

> [a-zA-z]+_[0-9]+,

Answer (score 0):

Use this regex:

```
sample_\d+\s,
```

And replace the matches with nothing !

Comment: @M42 that would match `sample_122      ,` which is not what is asked for.